# How to use theme functions in .module files?

Tags: forms, theming

I am trying to override theme_radio and theme_radios directly in MY_MODULE.module file.

For this purpose I declared these functions:

1)

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MY_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    // Theme for radio group.
    'custom_radios' => array(
      'render element' => array('element' => NULL),
    ),
    // Theme for single radio.
    'custom_radio' => array(
      'arguments' => array('element' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

2)

```
function theme_custom_radios($variables) {
  dpm('custom_radios');
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $attributes = array();
  if (isset($element['#id'])) {
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#id'];
  }
  $attributes['class'] = 'form-radios';
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $attributes['class'] .= ' ' . implode(' ', $element['#attributes']['class']);
  }
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['title'])) {
    $attributes['title'] = $element['#attributes']['title'];
  }
  return '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . (!empty($element['#children']) ? $element['#children'] : '') . '</div>';
}
```

3)

```
function theme_custom_radio($variables) {
  dpm('custom_radio');
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'radio';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  if (isset($element['#return_value']) && $element['#value'] !== FALSE && $element['#value'] == $element['#return_value']) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-radio'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';    
}
```

Then, to call my custom function I used hook_form_alter this way:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if(isset($form['nid']['#value'])){
      if($form['nid']['#value']=='472'){
        if($form_id=='uc_product_add_to_cart_form_472'){
            $form['attributes']['8']['#theme'] = 'custom_radios'; 
        }
      };
    }
}
```

Apparently the function theme_custom_radios is correctly called, the problem is that my radios buttons are now empty, I mean they are no more there.

Anybody has an idea?

/**** EDIT ****/

Here is the dpm output of my form:

```
attributes (Array, 7 elements)
    #theme (String, 24 characters ) uc_attribute_add_to_cart
    #id (String, 42 characters ) uc_product_add_to_cart_form-472-attributes
    1 (Array, 7 elements)
    8 (Array, 7 elements)
        #type (String, 6 characters ) radios
        #default_value (NULL)
        #options (Array, 4 elements)
            0 (String, 7 characters ) Color 1
            1 (String, 7 characters ) Color 2
            2 (String, 7 characters ) Color 3
            3 (String, 8 characters ) Color 17
        #ajax (Array, 2 elements)
        #title (String, 4 characters ) yeah
        #description (String, 0 characters )
        #required (String, 1 characters ) 1
    2 (Array, 7 elements)
    #tree (Boolean) TRUE
    #weight (Integer) -1
```

The options Color 1, Color 2, etc.. is what I need to change.

Actually I have a Drupal error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: element in theme_custom_radios() (line 85 of /home/www/dev/MY_WEBSITE/sites/all/modules/MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.module).
```

Am I supposed to send arguments in MY_MODULE_theme function? I was expecting that arguments would stay exactly the same, I just need to update the html code to add a span with the color as background

Comment: Is `$form['attributes']['8']` definitely a form element in its own right? As in, it has a `#type`, `#title`, etc? If not you should be putting the `#theme` on the element itself, i.e. `$form['attributes']`

Comment: I tried to putt #theme on $form['attributes'] but all form disappeared this time.